# Alignment issue with bibtex using IEEEtran class

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

Only the first reference of my bibliography is correctly aligned within the margins.  The other references go outside the margins to the left and right.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,cspaper,compsoc]{IEEEtran}      
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
% IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
% requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}

\begin{document}

\IEEEtriggeratref{5}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv, ExpObs} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

[Using .bib file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOmfW.png) (link to an image of the `.bib` file)

.bib file

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.9.2.
% Encoding: Cp1252

@ARTICLE{Abran1996,
author = {Abran, Alain and Robillard, Pierre N.},
title = {Function points analysis: An empirical study of its measurement processes},
journal = {Software Engineering, {IEEE} Transactions on},
year = {1996},
volume = {22},
pages = {895â€“910},
number = {12},
file = {[PDF] from    etsmtl.ca:C:\Users\jbeach\AppData\Roaming\Zotero\Zotero\Profiles\v8c7aoky.default\zotero\storage\T7CRESRV\Abran and Robillard - 1996 - Function points analysis An empirical study of it.pdf:application/pdf;Snapshot:C:\Users\jbeach\AppData\Roaming\Zotero\Zotero\Profiles\v8c7aoky.default\zotero\storage\MD2F63TH\login.html:text/html},
shorttitle = {Function points analysis},
url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=553638},
urldate = {2013-04-12}
}

@ARTICLE{Albrecht1983,
author = {Albrecht, Allan J. and Gaffney Jr, John E.},
title = {Software function, source lines of code, and development effort prediction:
a software science validation},
journal = {Software Engineering, {IEEE} Transactions on},
year = {1983},
pages = {639â€“648},
number = {6},
file = {Snapshot:C:\Users\jbeach\AppData\Roaming\Zotero\Zotero\Profiles\v8c7aoky.default\zotero\storage\AFMVVT4Z\login.html:text/html},
shorttitle = {Software function, source lines of code, and development effort prediction},
url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1703110},
urldate = {2013-04-05}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: You can add the output, and remove the leading `!`. Then, people can edit your question, and insert the `!` back again. Please also add the offending bibliography items in `ExpObs.bib`.

Comment: Please provide a *complete* [`minimal working example`](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) allowing us to reproduce the problem mentioned.

Comment: Please, at least post parts of your .bib file, not a mere picture of its contents.

Comment: I could not find a way to post a file, but the .bib file is similar for the many other entries.  If there is anything else I should post, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your example and it works fine:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass[10pt,journal,cspaper,compsoc]{IEEEtran}      
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{url}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
% IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
% requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{minimalbib.bib}
% This file was created with JabRef 2.9.2.
% Encoding: Cp1252

@ARTICLE{Abran1996,
author = {Abran, Alain and Robillard, Pierre N.},
title = {Function points analysis: An empirical study of its measurement processes},
journal = {Software Engineering, {IEEE} Transactions on},
year = {1996},
volume = {22},
pages = {895â€“910},
number = {12},
file = {[PDF] from    etsmtl.ca:C:\Users\jbeach\AppData\Roaming\Zotero\Zotero\Profiles\v8c7aoky.default\zotero\storage\T7CRESRV\Abran and Robillard - 1996 - Function points analysis An empirical study of it.pdf:application/pdf;Snapshot:C:\Users\jbeach\AppData\Roaming\Zotero\Zotero\Profiles\v8c7aoky.default\zotero\storage\MD2F63TH\login.html:text/html},
shorttitle = {Function points analysis},
url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=553638},
urldate = {2013-04-12}
}

@ARTICLE{Albrecht1983,
author = {Albrecht, Allan J. and Gaffney Jr, John E.},
title = {Software function, source lines of code, and development effort prediction:
a software science validation},
journal = {Software Engineering, {IEEE} Transactions on},
year = {1983},
pages = {639â€“648},
number = {6},
file = {Snapshot:C:\Users\jbeach\AppData\Roaming\Zotero\Zotero\Profiles\v8c7aoky.default\zotero\storage\AFMVVT4Z\login.html:text/html},
shorttitle = {Software function, source lines of code, and development effort prediction},
url = {http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1703110},
urldate = {2013-04-05}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Text\nocite{*}
\IEEEtriggeratref{5}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{minimalbib} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

File List:

```
 *File List*
IEEEtran.cls    2012/12/27 V1.8 by Michael Shell
  ot1ppl.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ppl.
verbatim.sty    2003/08/22 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
draftwatermark.sty    2006/06/30 1.0 Put a gray textual watermark on document p
ages
everypage.sty    2007/06/20 1.1 Hooks to run on every page
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
    cite.sty    2010/09/10  v 5.3
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX
 document
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
    test.bbl
  ot1phv.fd    2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv.
 ***********
```

Comment: Can you think of any reason why mine is not working?  Sorry, I am quite new to latex, and I spent much of yesterday and today trying to understand this issue.

Comment: @jbeach: You should take a copy of your document and comment line by line to find the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using IEEEtran with Overleaf. In my case, problems appeared with the urls: abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1703110 was misinterpreted as abs_{a}ll, Overleaf complained about math text out of an $$ enviroment and misalign the rest of the bibliography.
Try avoiding "url" and "doi" fields during your .bib exportation.

Comment: Hmmm... this should not be a problem if you use it properly (see [Underscore in bibtex url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383678/5764))...

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs if the URL has an underscore symbol. In your example that is the case for "/abs_all"

```
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1703110
```

An underscore in the URL should be avoided.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

putting `\` before the underscore should solve. I have the same problem and when I replaced the `_` with `\_` in the URL it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Could you please clarify how your answer is different from that of Matthias?