# LaTex Compiler in Springer Journal type misunderstands that "_" in biblio is a mathematical expression

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, compilation-error

LaTex Compiler thinks that "_" in biblio file is a mathematical expression that represents the beginning of subscript letter. Which library should I use or what should I do? My sample code is as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}

gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}

\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}

\smartqed
\usepackage{graphicx}

\journalname{Journal of Cryptographic Engineering}


\usepackage[acronym,toc,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\cite{10.1007/3-540-44983-3_4}

\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

My biblio file is as follows:

```
@InProceedings{10.1007/3-540-44983-3_4,
author="Aoki, Kazumaro
and Ichikawa, Tetsuya
and Kanda, Masayuki
and Matsui, Mitsuru
and Moriai, Shiho
and Nakajima, Junko
and Tokita, Toshio",
editor="Stinson, Douglas R.
and Tavares, Stafford",
title="Camellia: A 128-Bit Block Cipher Suitable for Multiple Platforms --- Design and Analysis",
booktitle="Selected Areas in Cryptography",
year="2001",
publisher="Springer Berlin Heidelberg",
address="Berlin, Heidelberg",
pages="39--56",
isbn = "978-3-540-44983-6",
doi = "10.1007/3-540-44983-3_4"
}
```

Comment: I doubt that your example really demonstrates your problem. You have neither a bibliography or a bibliographystyle command there.

Comment: I have edited the file and added the bibliography command. What is wrong now?

Comment: a _ in text is a math subscript even in bibliographies so would be an error but you have only shown `_` in a cite key which is not typeset and have not provided any example that shows the problem so it is hard to help oh as Ulrike says it's also in doi

Comment: your bib-style can't handle the doi correctly. you will have to enter is as `doi = "10.1007/3-540-44983-3\_4"`

Comment: Thank you to both of you for the help, the error is solved using \_ as you said.

Comment: Duplicate: [Underscore in bibtex url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/383678)