# How to source a youtube video - underlines causing subscript

Tags: multibib

I am trying to reference this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjNI9K1D_xo, and would like the link to be shown in the bibliography.

```
@online{vid1,
        title = {Introducing Meta},
        date = {2021},
        organization = {Meta},
        author = {Meta, Mark Zuckerberg},
        url ={https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjNI9K1D_xo},
    }
```

[image]

This comes out rather ugly. The referencing style currently used is IEEEtran, though I don't mind which one is used.

How do I

1. Reference a youtube video with URL, without an underscore in the URL messing things up? and
2. Make this look better in general?

New to latex so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Underscore in bibtex url](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383678/underscore-in-bibtex-url)

Comment: Load either `\usepackage{url}` or `\usepackage{hyperref}`. (It does not really make sense to load both, since `hyperref` internally loads `url`.) Most BibTeX styles that have a dedicated `url` field for URLs support `url`/`hyperref` in some way or another. **Do not escape the `_`.**

Comment: `author = {Meta, Mark Zuckerberg},` is probably not quite what you want. (It says that the author of the work is someone with last name "Meta" and first name "Mark Zuckerberg"). You may want `author = {Meta},` or `author = {Meta and Mark Zuckerberg},`. I'd probably drop the `organization = {Meta},` since Meta is already mentioned as author.